# Probability that $7^m+7^n$ is divisible by $5$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, divisibility

> If $m,n$ are chosen from the first hundred natural numbers with replacement, the probability that $7^m+7^n$ is divisible by $5$ is?

$$7^m+7^n=7^m(1+7^{n-m}), n\ge m$$
The above expression is divisible by $5$ only if $n-m=4k+2$. The max value of $k$ is $24$.

So is the number of possibilities $48$? ($24$ for each $n>m$ and $m>n$)

Comment: Note that $7^n\bmod 5$ takes the values $\{1,2,3,4\}$ equally likely when choosing $n$ from $1$ to $100$. So the probability is $1/4$.

Comment: There are 50 possible values of $k$: the range is $k=-25,\dots,24$.  But they are not equally likely, so that's not going to be an easy approach.

Comment: The expression $7^m+7^n$ has nice symmetry. In general one should be at least mildly reluctant to break symmetry.

Comment: When $m=n, 7^m + 7^n $ is not divisible by 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The possibilities of ending digits of $7^m$ or $7^n$ : $9,3,1,7$

Favourable cases : $(9,1),(3,7),(1,9),(7,3)$

Probability : $\frac{4}{4\times 4} =\frac{1}{4}$