# Probability that $7^m+7^n$ is divisible by $5$, where $m, n \in \{1,2,3,...,100 \}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> If the integers $m$ and $n$ are chosen at random between $1$ and $100$, then the probability that $7^m+7^n$ is divisible by $5$ equals?

My approach to this question was:

Using binomial theorem,
$$5\ |\ (7^m+7^n) \implies 5\ | \ (2^m + 2^n)$$

WLOG, let $m\leq n$. Then
$$5\ | \ (2^m + 2^n) \implies 5 \ | \ 2^m(2^{n-m}+1) \implies 5 \ | \ (2^{n-m}+1)$$

Which is possible only if $n-m=4k+2$, i.e. $n-m \in \{2,6,10,...,98\}$.

For $n-m=2$, $(n,m)\in\{(100,98), (99,97),...,(3,1)\}$. So there are $98$ ways.

For $n-m=6$, $(n,m)\in\{(100,94), (99,93),...,(7,1)\}$. So there are $94$ ways.

Similarly, we continue till $n-m=98$, where there are $2$ ways.

Total number of ways $=$ $$2+6+10+\ ...\ +94+98= \frac {25} 2 \left(2+98 \right)=25\times50$$.

And total number of ways of selecting $2$ numbers out of a hundred $= ^{100}C_2=50\times99$

Thus, probability is $$\frac {25\times50}{50\times99} = \frac {25}{99}$$

However, the answer is $\frac 1 4$. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

---

---

Please note that this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1672583/845186). I understand why the accepted answer there is correct, but I want to know the mistake I made.

Comment: @Evariste Thanks, I made the change

Comment: You're picking two distinct numbers but you can have $m=n$.

Comment: Whatever you get for $m$, the desired probability just becomes the probability of $n\equiv m+2\pmod{4}$. Every residue class has equal probability of appearing as we have 100 choices. So we would just get $1/4$.

Comment: Denominator should be $100C1 \times 100C1$ and in numerator, you should multiply by $2$ to include $m \gt n$ cases. Currently you have considered only $m \lt n$ cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you count the number of possibilities for $n,m$ you can have $n=m$.  These have half the chance of your cases with different $n,m$, so you would add $50$ to your count, getting $5000$ for the denominator and $\frac 14$ for the answer.